# Need help for javascript. Values and numbers in particular

Tags: javascript

Basically, I am trying to make grass on javascrpit. I want to condense the code because I keep adding 10 to the number for the tag 'moveTo". Is there any way to condense this? I just want shorter code without copying and pasting the code over and over just to add 10. For example, instead of copying moveTo(0,355) and then copying and pasting the code just to change moveTo to (0,365). I want to keep it short and simple. Is there anyway I could do this?

```
function drawBackground() {
  penColor("lightblue");
  dot(1000);
  moveTo(0, 0);
  penColor("yellow");
  dot(100);
  penUp();
  moveTo(100, 300);
}
drawBackground();
function drawGrass() {
  penWidth(7);
  turnTo(22);
  penColor("green");
  penDown();
  moveForward(25);
  turnRight(135);
  moveForward(25);
  turnLeft(135);
}

penUp();
moveTo(0, 355);
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
penUp();
moveTo(0, 365);
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
penUp();
moveTo(0, 375);
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
penUp();
moveTo(0, 385);
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
penUp();
moveTo(0, 395);
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
penUp();
moveTo(0, 405);
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
penUp();
moveTo(0, 415);
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
penUp();
moveTo(0, 425);
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
penUp();
moveTo(0, 425);
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
penUp();
moveTo(0, 425);
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
penUp();
moveTo(0, 435);
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
penUp();
moveTo(0, 445);
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
penUp();
moveTo(0, 455);
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
penUp();
moveTo(0, 465);
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
drawGrass();
```

Comment: You could make use of a `for` loop. Have you tried anything in this regard?

Comment: I have not. Could this help. for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use loops to reduce duplication.  Loop over the number of times you want to increase the spot by 10, then loop over each of those to draw grass 17 times each (like you have in your example) and then update your counter and move to the next 10.

You could replace all your code after your `function drawGrass(){}` declaration with this:

```
var counter = 355;
for (var i = 0; i < TEN_INTERVALS; i++){
   penUp();
   for (var x =0; x < 17; x++){
      drawGrass();
   }
   counter += 10;
   moveTo(0, counter);
}
```

Your code would look like this:

```
function drawBackground() {
  penColor("lightblue");
  dot(1000);
  moveTo(0, 0);
  penColor("yellow");
  dot(100);
  penUp();
  moveTo(100, 300);
}
drawBackground();
function drawGrass() {
  penWidth(7);
  turnTo(22);
  penColor("green");
  penDown();
  moveForward(25);
  turnRight(135);
  moveForward(25);
  turnLeft(135);
}
var counter = 355;
for (var i = 0; i < TEN_INTERVALS; i++){
   penUp();
   for (var x =0; x < 17; x++){
      drawGrass();
   }
   counter += 10;
   moveTo(0, counter);
}
```

You just need to replace `TEN_INTERVALS` with the number of times you want to increase by 10 (in your example it would be `13`).

Comment: What would go inside the loop?

Comment: Where would I declare it?